# httpResponse 401 unauthorized

Tags: c#, json, httpwebresponse

i want to post the json data to a webservice.

Here is the method:

```
public static Int32 SaveCashSale(string username, string key, CashSale cashSale)
{
    try
    {

        // Customize URL according to geo location parameters
        var url = string.Format(cashSaleUrl, username, key);

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";


        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string jsonData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
            {
                activity_date = cashSale.activity_date = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
                added_by = cashSale.added_by,
                amount_paid = cashSale.amount_paid,
                balance = cashSale.balance,
                currency = cashSale.currency,
                customer = cashSale.customer,
                grand_total = cashSale.grand_total,
            });

            streamWriter.Write(jsonData);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

        }

    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        using (WebResponse response = ex.Response)
        {
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;

            using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data);
                throw new Exception(sr.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

The system the following error message:
 **the remote server returned an error (401) unauthorized**.

at this line of the code:

```
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

the url fomrmat is :

```
private const string cashSaleUrl = "http://avaris.kwekud.com/api/v1/sales/cashsale/?username={0}&api_key={1}&format=json";
```

why the error, and how can i solve it ?

Comment: You have some kind of authorization? Maybe in the web.config?

Comment: @PatrickHofman no it is a windows app. so there is no web config file.

Comment: A web.config is for the web server (hence the name `web`)

Comment: ok but dont think it is related to the web conf, because with the similar code i can download json file from the server

Answer (score 2):

You should probably add credentials for your request.

Something like (just example - this will use default credentials):

```
 httpWebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
 httpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
 httpWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Comment: i added it but still given me the same error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Comment: I tried to look into the API. Seems that it also requires &format=json in the URL. Please add that as well.

Comment: i added it but the same error, i wonder what can be the problem.